# Activity com.android.settings.bluetooth.DevicePickerActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorVi

Tags: android, bluetooth

I was trying to auto send a file by Bluetooth but i have stagger at an error which i cannot figure it out. My app is a Survey and at the end the file is saved in the content:/Downloads/. At this stage it worked fine. But i was trying to send the file to nearby computer to process it.

```
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.settings.bluetooth.DevicePickerActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{21145e08 V.E..... R....... 0,0-580,452} that was originally added here
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:449)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:235)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at com.android.settings.bluetooth.DevicePickerActivity.initialize(DevicePickerActivity.java:220)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at com.android.settings.bluetooth.DevicePickerActivity.onCreate(DevicePickerActivity.java:75)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-10 16:04:59.027: E/WindowManager(18891):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the code originates after i choose what device i wanted to send the file.
Code Below

```
private void generateCsvFile(final String sFileName) {

        try {

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
            sharingIntent
                    .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                            "com.android.bluetooth",
                            "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.fromFile(report));
            startActivity(sharingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```

/* dialog that calls generateCsvFile

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Custom Dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

            // Correlates the layout and Dialog
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.optional);

            // Correlates the EditText variable to the layout object
            final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            final EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
            final EditText editTextCompany = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextCompany);
            final EditText editTextComments = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextComments);

            // Listener for Cancel Button within Dialog
            Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close Dialog without information gathering
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            // Listener for Submit button within Dialog
            Button submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Gathers info and stores in global variables
                    name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                    email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    company = editTextCompany.getText().toString();
                    comentarios = editTextComments.getText().toString();

                    // Close Dialog

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    generateCsvFile("teste");
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: is there any kind of dialog you are showing may be you are showing after finishing the activity.

Comment: You are showing a `Dialog` and not cancelling it properly. Before changing Acitivties, call `if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss(); }` assuming `dialog` is the name of your `Dialog` object

Comment: I'm already dismissing the dialog, i thought about that too. I updated the post.